# com.facebook.accountkit.ui.AccountKitActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class TextView

Tags: android, facebook, account-kit

Working on facebook account kit for android.

Got this issue on launch of login activity.

what is solution, dont able to find out,

Here is whole exception..

i all ready post this bug in facebook github page, but not got answer till now.

This code is working on some latest version of android, Andorid 4.0 this is not working.

```
                           Process: abc.co.com, PID: 14438
                                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{abc.co.com/com.facebook.accountkit.ui.AccountKitActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class TextView
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class TextView
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
                                                                     at com.facebook.accountkit.ui.LoginFragment.onCreateView(LoginFragment.java:38)
                                                                     at com.facebook.accountkit.ui.TitleFragmentFactory$TitleFragment.onCreateView(TitleFragmentFactory.java:42)
                                                                     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
                                                                     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
                                                                     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
                                                                     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
                                                                     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5240)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2168)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
                                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x1
                                                                     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(TypedArray.java:464)
                                                                     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3787)
                                                                     at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:623)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:59)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:55)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:103)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1013)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1072)
                                                                     at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:684)
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
                                                                     at com.facebook.accountkit.ui.LoginFragment.onCreateView(LoginFragment.java:38) 
                                                                     at com.facebook.accountkit.ui.TitleFragmentFactory$TitleFragment.onCreateView(TitleFragmentFactory.java:42) 
                                                                     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700) 
                                                                     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890) 
                                                                     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062) 
                                                                     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684) 
                                                                     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447) 
                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5240) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2168) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
                                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: have you solve this issue, bro?

Comment: Yes @Md.SajedulKarim . That just needs to update with letest account kit sdk.